# Create one index per Django model in Haystack

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I got basic Haystack working with Django as per the [Getting Started of Haystack's docs.](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.1/tutorial.html) with Elasticsearch. I have two Django models: Product and Store, and have created corresponding SearchIndex classes for them.

When I run the `python manage.py rebuild_index` command, only one index is being built and that contains documents of both my Product and Store objects. 
How do I get Haystack to create separate indices in Elasticsearch, one for Product and one for Store?